# can't resizing images in Universal Image Loader before displaying

Tags: android, image-resizing, universal-image-loader

I am using of Android Universal Image Loader and I want to resize images my recycler view items and my slider. I used this method in my slider's viewPager:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

  private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
  private Context context;
  private DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions2;
  private ImageLoaderConfiguration config2;

  public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageUrls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels ;
    final float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels ;

    byte[] toEncrypt = (G.getPremiumState()[0] + ":" + G.getPremiumState()[1]).getBytes();
    String encryptedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encryptedCredentials);

    defaultOptions2 = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
      .cacheInMemory(true)
      .cacheOnDisk(true)
      .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading_02)
      .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_empty_white_box)
      .extraForDownloader(headers)
      .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
      @Override
      public Bitmap process(Bitmap bmp) {
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) dpWidth, (int) (dpHeight/2), false);
      }
    })
      .build();

    config2 = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(G.context)
      .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions2)
      .imageDownloader(new AuthDownloader(G.context))
      .build();
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return imageUrls.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view);


    final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slideImage);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); //Get singleton instance
    imageLoader.init(config2);
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls.get(position), img);
    imageLoader.handleSlowNetwork(true);
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((FrameLayout) object);
  }
}
```

And here is my recyclerView adapter:

```
public class BaseListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;
  private ImageLoaderConfiguration config;

  public BaseListAdapter(List<PList> menuItems, Context mContext) {
    this.menuItems = menuItems;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.activitySingleGroup = (ActivitySingleGroup) mContext;

    byte[] toEncrypt = (G.getPremiumState()[0] + ":" + G.getPremiumState()[1]).getBytes();
    String encryptedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encryptedCredentials);

    defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
      .cacheInMemory(true)
      .cacheOnDisk(true)
      .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading_02)
      .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_empty_white_box)
      .extraForDownloader(headers)
      .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap process(Bitmap bmp) {
          return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 120, 120, false);
        }
      })
      .build();

    config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(activitySingleGroup)
      .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
      .imageDownloader(new AuthDownloader(activitySingleGroup))
      .build();

  }

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtPrice;
    TextView txtCode;
    ImageView imgDefault;
    LinearLayout parentLayout;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
      super(v);

      txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
      txtPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
      txtCode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_code);
      imgDefault = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_defaultImage);
      parentLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
      coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

    }
  }

  @Override
  public BaseListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    // Create a new View
    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(activitySingleGroup).inflate(R.layout.activity_normal_group_recycler, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //Download and Load Default Image from server into imgDefault ImageView
    String url = "http://185.2.14.77:8080/api/images/download/";

    if (menuItems.get(position).getPDefaultImage().getIId() != null) {

      url += menuItems.get(position).getPDefaultImage().getIId();

      ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
      imageLoader.init(config);
      imageLoader.displayImage(url, holder.imgDefault);
      imageLoader.handleSlowNetwork(true);

    } else {
      holder.imgDefault.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_01);
    }

    holder.txtCode.setText("" + menuItems.get(position).getPCode());
    holder.txtName.setText(menuItems.get(position).getPName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(menuItems.get(position).getPPrice()));
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

        prepareBottomSheet(view, position, holder.coordinatorLayout);
      }
    });

    // Here you apply the animation when the view is bound
    //setAnimation(holder.parentLayout, position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    if (menuItems.size() > 0) {

      return menuItems.size();

    } else {
      return 0;
    }

  }
```

I used the same method for both of them but Images will be resized in my recyclerView but they don't resize in my viewPager.

Answer (score 0):

I got it from an old question a time ago, put it inside your `onBindViewHolder`

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
final Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagem, 0, imagem.length);
options.outHeight = originalImage.getHeight();
options.outWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 100, 100);
```

call this method passing the options (above), the requested Width and height.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps
            // both height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```